# AppleScript press and hold key

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript

Trying to run an apple script on a full screen application made in unity.  I'm trying to press and hold a key.  It doesn't seem to press and hold.  For some reason it only enters the character once rather than many times.  If I'm in the full screen application and I physically press and hold "a" on the keyboard i"ll end up seeing "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".  But when I run this script I only see one single "a".  Am I supposed to just send multiple single presses?  If so, what's the point of key down and key up?

```
tell application "MyThingy"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        key down "124"
        delay (random number from 0.5 to 3)
        key up "124"

        key down "124"
        delay (random number from 3 to 4)
        key up "124"
    end tell
end tell
```

Do note I'm ultimately running this script from python, but I'm testing it in Applescript editor and getting the same results.

Comment: That cannot work. `key down / up` affects only the modifier keys (⇧, ⌃, ⌥ and ⌘)

Comment: @vadian That makes sense... So should I instead send multiple key presses with a sleep between them?  Or do you know of a better way to do this?

Comment: You can only send a single keystroke per code line. It's up to you how to use that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info.  So when I physically press and hold a key on the keyboard is it sending multiple events?  Or just a down and an up event?  I'm just trying to figure out of the applescript APIs are limiting me and if I should consider something else or just stick with my keystroke + sleep loop...

Comment: The keyboard repeats keystroke events as long as the key is down. AppleScript however does not.

Comment: Interesting... Looks like you can even change how fast keys repeat! https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18410?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US